# Position element relative to image

Tags: css

I already read tons of other questions but i still can't get a clue how do i propely position text inside images. I get almost all i need but i still need to position my image center to it's parent's.

```css
.imageholder {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.discount {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: rgba(232, 63, 66, 1);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 80px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.black_opacity_background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="imageholder">
  <div class='black_opacity_background'></div>
  <div class="discount">-50%</div>
  <img src="https://d2npu017ljjude.cloudfront.net/images/regular-43/w378/h283/96583-4.jpg">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Amiths/poxj7kfq/

In this example i want to center `imageholder` relative to my main view. Since i use `float: left;` for  `imageholder` i dont know how can i achieve both things.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```css
.bigContainer {text-align:center;}

.center {display:inline-block}

.imageholder {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.discount {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: rgba(232, 63, 66, 1);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 80px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.black_opacity_background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="bigContainer">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="imageholder">
      <div class='black_opacity_background'></div>
      <div class="discount">-50%</div>
      <img src="https://d2npu017ljjude.cloudfront.net/images/regular-43/w378/h283/96583-4.jpg">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```